# Add a column on a dataframe

Tags: r

I have an R problem if you can help.

```
x <- data.frame("LocationCode" = c("ESC3","RIECAA6","SJHMAU","RIE104","SJH11","SJHAE","RIEAE1","WGH54","RIE205","GSBROB"), "HospitalNumber" = c("701190923R","2905451068","700547389X","AN11295201","1204541612","104010665","800565884R","620063158W","600029720K","1112391223"),"DisciplineName" = c("ESC Biochemistry", "RIE Haematology","SJH Biochemistry","RIE Biochemistry","SJH Biochemistry","WGH Biochemistry","ESC Biochemistry","WGH Biochemistry","SJH Biochemistry","RIE Haematology"))
```

From the dataframe above i do wish to add a new  column (CRN) made up of all "HospitalNumber" rows with 9 digits plus  1 letter at the end (e.g 701190923R), create another column (TIT) with the rest of the rows which does not meet the 1st criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in base using the code

```
# Identify cases which match 9 digits then one letter
CRMMatch <- grepl("^\\d{9}[[:alpha:]]$", as.character(x$HospitalNumber))
#Create columns from Hospital number among the matches or those that do not match
x$CRN[CRMMatch] <- as.character(x$HospitalNumber)[CRMMatch]
x$TIT[!CRMMatch] <- as.character(x$HospitalNumber)[!CRMMatch]
# clean up by removing the variable created of matches
rm(CRMMatch)
```

A `dplyr` version could be

```
library(dplyr)
x <-
  x %>% 
  mutate(CRN = if_else(grepl("^\\d{9}[[:alpha:]]$", as.character(HospitalNumber)),as.character(HospitalNumber), NA_character_),
         TIT = if_else(!grepl("^\\d{9}[[:alpha:]]$", as.character(HospitalNumber)),as.character(HospitalNumber), NA_character_))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect what you need with the instruction

```
library(stringr)
str_which(x$HospitalNumber,"[:digit:][:alpha:]")
```

and you get:

```
> str_which(x$HospitalNumber,"[:digit:][:alpha:]")
[1] 1 3 7 8 9
```

Then you know what positions you need and what you don't

Answer (score 0):

Quite similar to Kerry Jackson's approach but using `ifelse` in base R. I have also converted your `x$HospitalNumber` from factor to character from the start, assuming that this is what you really want:

```
x[2] <- as.character( x[ , 2 ] )
x$CRN <- ifelse( grepl( "^\\d{9}[[:alpha:]]$", x$HospitalNumber) , x$HospitalNumber, "" )
x$TIT <- ifelse( x$CRN != "", "", x$HospitalNumber )
```

gives you

```
> x
   LocationCode HospitalNumber   DisciplineName        CRN        TIT
1          ESC3     701190923R ESC Biochemistry 701190923R           
2       RIECAA6     2905451068  RIE Haematology            2905451068
3        SJHMAU     700547389X SJH Biochemistry 700547389X           
4        RIE104     AN11295201 RIE Biochemistry            AN11295201
5         SJH11     1204541612 SJH Biochemistry            1204541612
6         SJHAE      104010665 WGH Biochemistry             104010665
7        RIEAE1     800565884R ESC Biochemistry 800565884R           
8         WGH54     620063158W WGH Biochemistry 620063158W           
9        RIE205     600029720K SJH Biochemistry 600029720K           
10       GSBROB     1112391223  RIE Haematology            1112391223
```